# nonsilent delivery of a WMRM DRM license via ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drm

Is it possible to do nonsilent delivery of a WMRM DRM license via ASP.NET (ideally MVC)?

I have silent delivery working fine.

All the [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649429(VS.85).aspx) [from the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649408(VS.85).aspx) (WMRM10.1) are in asp - of which I have no experience (I went from PHP to ASP.NET).

It looks like I need to implement the actual issuance in vbscript or JavaScript included with the html. Is this right?

Does anyone have an example of doing nonsilent license issuance in JavaScript/ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this working using a view very similar to this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<LicenceViewModel>" %>
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function Storev71License()
{
   LicenseObj.StoreLicense('<%= Model.Licence %>');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Storev71License()">
<object classid="clsid:A9FC132B-096D-460B-B7D5-1DB0FAE0C062" height="0" id="LicenseObj" width="0">
  <embed mayscript type="application/x-drm-v2" hidden="true">
</object>
<p>You have received a license for this movie. Click Play.</p>
</body>
</html>
```